# What is VENDOR folder for in Kohana 3.3?

Tags: kohana, kohana-3.3

In DOCROOT folder of Kohana 3.3 there is a new `vendor` folder.

What is it for?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not supposed to be there. It was leftover from composer.

Comment: So should I simply delete it? Is it useless?

Comment: Pretty much. If you use composer (to install phpunit or something), stuff will be put there.

Answer (score 4):

It is where you can drop external libraries for use with Kohana.

For example, this is where I put my 3rd party Twitter API.

Answer (score 1):

May be irrelevant but for newbies to KOHANA 3.3, that Vendor directory is meant for extending/adding custom vendor based functionality, similar to the plug-ins concept. And it's not new addition to kohana 3.3.

Also as @zombor mentioned it's a-left-over in DOCROOT.

Rest is all clear in my opinion.